# For loop iteration in a range does not work in bash

Tags: linux, shell

How do I iterate over a range of numbers in Bash when the range is given.

my code is like

```
for i in {1..5}
do
   echo "Welcome $i times"
done
```

And I am expecting

```
Welcome 1 times
Welcome 2 times
...
```

However I got something like

```
Welcome {1..5} times
```

my bash version is

```
GNU bash, version 5.0.3(1)-release (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu)
Copyright (C) 2019 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>
```

Comment: That will happen if you are really missing `#!/bin/bash` as the first line and it ends up using `sh` instead of `bash`. Is that really your full code or you didn't paste in the first line?

Comment: Ah! That is exactly the reason! Thanks!

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21288175/bash-foreach-loop-works-differently-when-executed-from-sh-file (can happen to anyone)

Answer (score 3):

Script is missing the first line:

`#!/bin/bash`

Result is that a different shell may be running the script. In particular the error will occur if the script is run by `sh`. This is because `{1..5}` is a bash sequence expression and is not supported by some other shells like `sh`.